# How to connect MongoDB docker by Studio 3T?

Tags: mongodb, docker, studio3t

I am using docker image https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo/  (Latest MongoDB version)

I run command

```
docker run --name some-mongo -d mongo
```

Then I install [Studio 3T](https://studio3t.com) 
I enter connection information like this

[image]

but I can't connect. What is correct connection must declare in Studio 3T in this case? How to connect MongoDB instance (docker) by Studio 3T?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to export the port you want to use in your docker command. e.g.

```
docker run -p 127.0.0.1:27017:27017 --name some-mongo -d mongo
```

This opens the port of the container on your host machine.

Comment: I can connect to to my docker mongo via Robo 3T but not Studio 3T (I've imported the connection from Robo) But it can't connect

Comment: This is not working for me. I get "Fail to load list of databases" as a result of a login attempt.

Comment: @Rick Ronger  How can this command be used with docker-compose? I'm quite new to all and very confused?

Comment: @lomse you can use this tool to convert ithttps://bucherfa.github.io/dcc-web/ (I recommend removing the name, as docker compose has a build in system for managing container names.

Comment: @dragonalvaro and fabien these errors are quite generic, they can have multiple causes. I suggest searching for them, as they are probably already asked once.

Answer (score 7):

- Click New Connection
- Enter the Connection name
- Click on `From URI`
- Enter the URI in the following format
  `mongodb://{username}:{password}@{ip_address}:{port}/?authSource=admin`
- Click `OK`
- Click `Test Connection`
- Works?

  - No: Check your username, password, etc
  - yes: Congrats!

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the IP address where the Docker container is running. On Mac docker runs in the background inside a linux VM that has its own IP. Thus `localhost` will not work.

To find the IP, run `docker-machine env default` and set this IP in the Server field.

Answer (score 1):

I was running mongodb with wsl2 and docker, so I needed just to add "from uri", and set up ip_adress with the ip from wsl2.

Explanation:

1. Uri: This connection string is the way we can talk to robo 3t understand how to connect with our mongodb server.
2. ip_address: Because of docker creates containers that are similar to servers, each container has an ip_adress, so to have access to this mongodb server, we need to find the ip_adress from the container that we need.

I used this URI:

**mongodb://{username}:{password}@{ip_address}:{port}/?authSource=admin**

**username** = MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME

**password** = MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD

**port** = 27017(docker container port will be set up on docker parameter "-p")

**ip_address** = Ip from wsl2 in my case, or localhost if you running docker locally.

This was my command to run the container on the first time :

**docker container run -d -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=mongouser -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=mongopwd -p 27017:27017 -v mongo_vol:/data/db mongo:4.4.3**

Comment: @Yunnosch do you think that is enough ? I tried to improve just little, for the answer no became so big.

Answer (score 0):

for those on windows kindly check in task manager and make sure you don't have a local installation of mongo db server running then use `localhost` in address/connection string

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem connecting Studio 3T with MongoDB earlier this week, and it consumed my entire working day, so I gave up on using Studio 3T to ensure time for other things and an alternative.  Today I found this short video tutorial by Studio 3T on how to connect Studio 3T with MongoDB.  Following the directions, I was surprised that a connection was made successfully.

I recommend you watch/follow this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Ka3-HGNlYE

If it helps you, remember to tick this answer.